# dependency errors when installing jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: dependencies, jdk

Attempting to install JDK-11.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 Failed dependencies.  I have matched the list to the directories indicated and found no items missing.

This is the command used:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh /home/tom/Downloads/jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.rpm
```

The rpm is as directly downloaded from Oracle.

What am I missing?

The message says to use Alien instead of rpm.  What is Alien and what command string would I use to install this rpm?

```
tom@user-UX31E:/bin$ sudo rpm -Uvh /home/tom/Downloads/jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.rpm
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
warning: /home/tom/Downloads/jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/basename is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/cat is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/cp is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/gawk is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/grep is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/ln is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/ls is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/mkdir is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/mv is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/pwd is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/rm is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/sed is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/sort is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/touch is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /usr/bin/cut is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /usr/bin/dirname is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /usr/bin/expr is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /usr/bin/find is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /usr/bin/tail is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /usr/bin/tr is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /usr/bin/wc is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
    /bin/sh is needed by jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64
tom@user-UX31E://$
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the error messages RPM should not be used to install packages in Ubuntu. The package should be converted to Debain format (.deb) using alien and installed from the .deb file.